# How do I troubleshoot a Kenmore HE washer with an f-21 error?

Tags: appliances, washing-machine

We have a kenmore elite smartwash quiet pak 2 (723 wt-wt).

It starts the normal wash cycle and about 35 mins in, it will not go to a rinse cycle and it stops.Error F21 or Sud comes up. I can not proceed from there. since yesterday we have been having problems with it unlocking, it appears like it not fully draining. We cant drain wont open door tried following the operation instructions on the front tried resetting power still gets stuck at f21 / SUD wont drain

Comment: Has this always been a problem (since installing the washer), or has it just started (washer worked fine previously)? Where is the washer draining (washtub, standpipe, other)? Is the drain line extended beyond the factory supplied hose?

Comment: From my research, F21 is a slow drain error. Which means the washer is taking too long to drain. This points to either a problem with the discharge pump, or the plumbing of the drain.

Comment: ya we found the problem, it was a large chunk of cloth, an eye glasses cleaning cloth about 5" x 5" balled up and stuck in the drain pump exit hole, surprised something this large found its way down there

Comment: the washer is 6 years old

Comment: I am having the same problem right now! Where do I start??

Comment: We had to take apart the drain assembly which is below the main door wasn't difficult to take apart if the drain is clogged that's a good place to start

Comment: Make sure you get as much water out of the drum as you can and be ready for water when you clear your drain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

f21 - Long drain time - Pump was plugged

ya we found the problem, it was a large chunk of cloth, an eye glasses cleaning cloth about 5" x 5" balled up and stuck in the drain pump exit hole, surprised something this large found its way down there